# How to decolorize blue fabric whitener?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

After adding 4 drops of fabric whitener in water, what should I add to decolorize the solution and turn it clear like water?

Comment: Try a very mild solution of bleach such a that sold under the trade name of 'Milton'

Comment: Can Dettol (Chloroxylenol) work?

Comment: This is probably better as an antiseptic than an oxidising agent.